# Newton's evaluation of 1 + 1/3 - 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 + 1/11

Tags: calculus, newton

I had asked the following question on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764826/newtons-evaluation-of-1-1-3-1-5-1-7-1-9-1-11), and I was directed to this exchange.  There is a nice solution in the comments there, but perhaps someone here can add some additional insight?

How might have Newton evaluated the following series?

$$\sqrt{2} \, \frac{\pi}{4} = 1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} - \cdots$$

The method of the [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462803/showing-pi-2-sqrt3-1-1-51-7-1-111-13-1-171-19-cdots) applies by setting $x=\pi/4$ in the Fourier series for $f(x) = \pi/2 - x/2$ and then subtracting the extraneous terms (which are a multiple of the Gregory-Leibniz series for $\pi/4$).

I read that this series appears in a letter from Newton to Leibniz.  However, I do not have access the letter which appears in [this volume](https://www.cambridge.org/ec/academic/subjects/physics/history-philosophy-and-foundations-physics/correspondence-isaac-newton-volume-2?format=PB&isbn=9780521085991).

Comment: This question is already answered in [Brian Tung's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3764895/152568) in the MSE thread, and [Mackinnon's article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3620373) he cites gives even more details, including a facsimile of Newton's letter with translation of relevant excerpts. What exactly would you like us to add?

Comment: @Conifold Nothing needs to be added.  Brian Tung's post appeared after I posted here.  I think the MSE thread has answered my question.  I can delete this question if that is appropriate.  Or we can leave this here if it's a useful reference via your link above.